# Load html template on an es6 application

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I have setup the cross browser extension boilerplate
https://github.com/EmailThis/extension-boilerplate
I want to be able to load html content inside my javascript code example

```
import contentTemplate from "../content.html";
```

I have found some plugins but they all work with webpack, 
how can I do the above without webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that with the following plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string